# How to add multiple items to the same property in CMake's set_target_properties() function?

Tags: build, cmake

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE 
                       ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary.so)
```

Will add that shared library. However, I want multiple shared libraries to be added.

I tried the following:

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE 
                       "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_1.so" 
                       "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_2.so")
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Lists in CMake are just strings separated with ";". Try `"${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_1.so;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_2.so"`.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the answer to the question and my comment on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE` specifies the location of a single file. You can create two targets and then link with them:

```
add_library(mysharedlibrary_1 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(mysharedlibrary_1 PROPERTIES 
         IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_1.so)

add_library(mysharedlibrary_2 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(mysharedlibrary_2 PROPERTIES
          IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_2.so)

add_library(MyTarget INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(MyTarget INTERFACE mysharedlibrary_1 mysharedlibrary_2)
```

Answer (score 7):

Because the [`set_target_properties()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) can set multiple properties in one call, you have to make the argument following `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE` appear as one argument. To achieve this, you can concatenate the libraries into a semicolon-separated list:

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE
    "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_1.so;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_2.so"
)
```

Or, you can use the `set()` command to create the list for you. You can set these libraries in a variable, then let the list variable be expanded in the `set_target_properties()` call:

```
set(MY_SHARED_LIBS
    "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_1.so" 
    "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_2.so"
)

set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${MY_SHARED_LIBS}"
)
```

---

A third option is to use [`set_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html), which allows you to list each library as a separate argument, which may help provide more correct formatting:

```
set_property(TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE 
    ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_1.so
    ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/mysharedlibrary_2.so
)
```

Comment: I am trying to pass library files for linking. If I do what you said here, in my compilation step cmake interprets it as `"$PREFIX/lib/mysharedlib_1.so;$PREFIX/lib/mysharedlib_2.so"`. But what I actually want is `$PREFIX/lib/mysharedlib_1.so $PREFIX/lib/mysharedlib_2.so`. Note that I dont even want the `""`

Comment: @Chani Ok, your question was vague when stating "*But this doesn't work*", but your goals are more clear now. I've added a third option to my answer that may help with the formatting issue you are seeing.

Comment: The third option does not work for me, at least with VS2019.